# Who owns this email? ... @cloudtestlabaccounts.com

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-test-lab

I'm developing an Android app that uses Firebase login, still using the old Firebase console.

After published the apk into the alpha channel of Google Player Developer Console, I found the following **strange** account in my Firebase:

**name** = Nuage Laboratoire

**email** = 123xyz...@cloudtestlabaccounts.com

Anyone know who is the owner? 
Is it a test made by Firebase / Google or I have been hacked?

In Firebase Login & Auth I just disabled Email & Password Authentication also if I didnt found a Registered Users like @cloudtestlabaccounts,com

Now, the only way to login is Google Authentication.

Any suggestion about?

Comment: http://www.whoismind.com/whois/cloudtestlabaccounts.com.html

Comment: Beat me to it Mike :)

Comment: what is this whoismind.com thing? does the URL change? redirecting to some unknown sites

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It looks like you probably ran your app through [Firebase Test Lab for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/) (previously Cloud Test Lab) or used the the [Google Play pre launch report](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en) at least once, which will happen when you publish to an alpha or beta channel on the Play Store and opt into the free test.  When you do a [Robo test](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/robo-ux-test) with FTL, it will attempt to log into your app with a test Google account in order to discover all of your app's features.

The name of the user is intended to be clever.  "Nuage Laboratoire" is French for "Cloud Lab" (Firebase Test Lab used to be called "Cloud Test Lab").

Comment: Actually "Nuage Laboratoire" means "Cloud Lab", "Test Lab" is translated as "Laboratoire Test"

Comment: So how do we disable this? These users are getting created and welcome emails are getting sent to them, returning undelivered!

Comment: @badrobot Did you found anything on this yet ? Am facing the same problem.

Comment: @kvaruna your only options are to disable pre-launch reports when releasing a new version of your app, which is not ideal as these reports are quite handy.
The other option is to add logic in your code to ignore emails address with the domain "cloudtestlabaccounts.com" which all of these test users seem to have.

Comment: @badrobot Yeah. Initially was worried but now am not even thinking about it. Thanks.

Comment: @DougStevenson I didn't run my app through Firebase test lab for android. What could be other possible reasons for this sign in?

Comment: @KartikWatwani I also did not run any Firebase tests, and got these accounts signed up. Any other reasons why these would pop up?

Comment: @SeopYoon you probably don't care anymore, but for posterity, when you upload your app the google play store and the apple app store part of their automated testing process is to run fake users through your app to make sure the inputs don't error.